# CodeChef - Chef and Lucky Number: Why is no output being printed?

Tags: java, runtime-error

[CodeChef - Chef and Lucky Number (DOUBL)](https://www.codechef.com/problems/DOUBL)

My program is running successfully on ideone but nothing is being printed. When I submit my code on CodeChef WA error is shown. WA error means Wrong Answer.

Below is the code:

```
import java.io.*;
class doubl
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
    {
        BufferedReader obj = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        int c = 0;
        int T = Integer.parseInt(obj.readLine());
        if (T>=1 && T<=1000)
        {
            while (T>0)
            {
                int N = Integer.parseInt(obj.readLine());
                if (N>=1 && N<=1000000)
                {
                    for(int i = 2; i<N; i++)
                    {
                        if(N%i == 0)
                        {
                            c++;
                        }
                    }
                    if(c==1)
                    {
                        if(N%2 == 0)
                        {
                            System.out.println("LUCKY NUMBER");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            System.out.println("Sorry");
                        }
                    }

                }
                T--;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: If I understand this problem correctly, the only "Lucky Number"s that have factors of 1, 2, and N is 1 & 2.  No other number to my knowledge satisfies that condition.

Answer (score 2):

This question on [Codechef](https://www.codechef.com/problems/DOUBL) has problems with its test data. That's why there is no successful submissions there.

The problem statement says that :

> Mr. Chef has been given a number N. He has a tendency to double whatever he get. So now he has got the number N with him and **he has multiplied the number N by 2**. Now Chef is superstitious. He believes in something known as Lucky Number. **His lucky number is defined as any number, which
>   when multiplied by 2 has no other factors other than 1,2, and N.** If the number is lucky all you have to do is print “LUCKY NUMBER”. If the number is not a lucky number, print “Sorry”.

If you notice the bold lines, it says the number N is first multiplied by 2. Hence it becomes 2N. Now it again says the multiplied number i.e **2N has no other factors other than 1,2 and N. But 2N is a factor of itself.** So there is no Lucky Number. So the problem is poorly set. Hope this helps.

P.S. - Now they have also put this note.

> **NOTE: DUE TO SOME ISSUE IN TEST DATA WE HAVE TEMPORARILY STOPPED THE SUBMISSION.**

Comment: @user132458-You could've pointed out at my incorrect answer. I also missed the whole line meaning. Thanks, I am deleting my answer and +1'd your answer...